# How to parameterize the inline code, text, together with R code chunk in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

In my Rmarkdown report, most of sections have the same text, inline code and R code chunk. Is it possible to **parameterize** them? For example the below image, is it possible to use something like for loop to produce them instead of repeating similar code 3 times?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps using a 'child' document in this situation might be helpful. For more info see  https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main RMD file,

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  id = 1:3,
  fruit = c("apple", "orange", "banana"),
  sold = c(10, 20, 30)
)
```

```
res <- lapply(dat$id, function(x) {
  knitr::knit_child(
    'template.Rmd', envir = environment(), quiet = TRUE
  )
})
cat(unlist(res), sep = '\n')
```

In template.RMD,

```
current_dat <- filter(dat, id == x)
```

```
# Section: `r  current_dat$fruit`
```

```
current_dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fruit, y = sold)) + geom_col()
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the simplest wat to achieve this is to use `results = 'asis'` and `cat()` below is a minimal RMarkdown file.

````
---
title: "Minimal example"
---

```{R results = "asis"}
for (i in 1:3) {
 x <- runif(10)
 cat("# section", floor(i), "\n")
 plot(x)
 # line break
 cat("\n\n")
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But in my case, each section has a lot of information and format is quite complicated. This will make cat(...) very complicated